# Tradingview strategy tester and pinescipt tp/sl problem

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

thanks for checking this.

I am new to pinescript and strategy tester and when i use limit/stop function to set my tp/sl, it just doesnt work out.

For example, if i want my tp=(postion average open price*1.1) and sl=(position average open price*0.95), the strategy tester does not follow and i am unable to figure out why...

```
//@version=5
strategy("7", overlay=true)

fast=input.int(14,"fast length",minval=2,maxval=200,step=5)
slow=input.int(28,"slow length",minval=4,maxval = 400,step = 5)
fastma=ta.sma(close,fast)
slowma=ta.sma(close,slow)

longcon=ta.crossover(fastma,slowma)
shortcon=ta.crossunder(fastma,slowma)

if(longcon)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("exit","Long",limit=strategy.position_avg_price*1.1,stop=strategy.position_avg_price*0.95)

if(shortcon)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("exit","Short",limit=strategy.position_avg_price*0.9,stop=strategy.position_avg_price*1.05)
`
```

[Strategy tester result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMpfl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your exit orders conditionally unless you really mean it. You can put them in the global scope.

```
//@version=5
strategy("7", overlay=true)

fast=input.int(14,"fast length",minval=2,maxval=200,step=5)
slow=input.int(28,"slow length",minval=4,maxval = 400,step = 5)
fastma=ta.sma(close,fast)
slowma=ta.sma(close,slow)

longcon=ta.crossover(fastma,slowma)
shortcon=ta.crossunder(fastma,slowma)

if(longcon)
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)


if(shortcon)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)

strategy.exit("exit","Long",limit=strategy.position_avg_price*1.1,stop=strategy.position_avg_price*0.95, comment_profit="L-TP", comment_loss="L-SL")
strategy.exit("exit","Short",limit=strategy.position_avg_price*0.9,stop=strategy.position_avg_price*1.05, comment_profit="S-TP", comment_loss="S-SL")
```

I would also suggest, you use `calc_on_order_fills=true` in your `strategy()` call. There are some cases where your backtest is not accurate. Those cases are where your exit would be on the same bar as your entry. `calc_on_order_fills` would fix that problem for you.